# c++ class does not detect sym links

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stat

i have a c++ class that reads info about a file using stat. it sets dir and reg true on the respective files just fine but lnk remains false when i test it on a known sym link on my ubuntu PC ("/vmlinuz.old"). it sets reg true in this situation. must of my code is ref'ed here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat (stroll to the buttom)

```
class file_info
{
  public:
    string size;
    string owner;
    string group;
    string path;

    string acc_time;
    string mod_time;
    string cre_time;

    bool read;
    bool write;
    bool exec;

    bool dir;
    bool lnk;
    bool reg;
    bool fail;

  private:
    struct stat f_stat;

    void set_size()
    {
      string raw_size = to_string(f_stat.st_size);
      unsigned int len = raw_size.size();
      size = "";

      if (len <= 3)
      {
        size += raw_size;
        size += "Bytes";
        return;
      }

      size += raw_size[len - 1];
      size += ".";
      size += raw_size[len - 2];

      if ((len > 3) && (len < 6))         size += "KB";
      else if ((len >= 6) && (len < 9))   size += "MB";
      else if ((len >= 9) && (len < 12))  size += "GB";
      else if ((len >= 12) && (len < 15)) size += "TB";
      else if ((len >= 15) && (len < 18)) size += "PB";
      else if ((len >= 18) && (len < 21)) size += "EB";
      else size = "OL";
    }

  private:
    void get_info()
    {
      switch (f_stat.st_mode & S_IFMT)
      {
        case S_IFDIR: dir = true; break;
        case S_IFREG: reg = true; break;
        case S_IFLNK: lnk = true; break;
        default: fail = true; break;
      }

      if (!fail)
      {
        if (f_stat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) read = true;
        if (f_stat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) write = true;
        if (f_stat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) exec = true;

        struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(f_stat.st_uid);
        struct group *gr = getgrgid(f_stat.st_gid);

        if (pw != NULL) owner = pw->pw_name;
        if (gr != NULL) group = gr->gr_name;

        set_size();       
        acc_time = ctime(&f_stat.st_atime);
        mod_time = ctime(&f_stat.st_mtime);
        cre_time = ctime(&f_stat.st_ctime);

        acc_time.erase(acc_time.end() - 1, acc_time.end());
        mod_time.erase(mod_time.end() - 1, mod_time.end());
        cre_time.erase(cre_time.end() - 1, cre_time.end());
      }
    }

  public:
    file_info(string file): dir(false),
                            lnk(false),
                            reg(false),
                            fail(false),
                            read(false),
                            write(false),
                            exec(false)
    {
      path = file;

      if (stat(file.c_str(), &f_stat))
      {
        fail = true;
      }
      else
      {
        get_info();
      }
    } 
};
```

Comment: why do you have multiple public: and privates:? O.o

Comment: i'm well aware of that, i'm just concentrating in having working code for now. this is hardly final stuff here.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you are using the stat() system call to check if a file is a symbolic link or not, using the S_IFLNK flag. Here is a quote from the man page:

```
stat() stats the file pointed to by path and fills in buf.

lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if path is a symbolic link,
then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.
```

Try using lstat() instead of stat(). stat() follows the link, and returns that the file the link links to is indeed a directory or regular file.

Answer (score 1):

`stat()` returns information about the file to which a symbol link points... try `lstat()`

Comment: hmmm based on tiny's or your answer, i should find a way to use lstat but how do i know when to use it when i don't know what type of file i'm dealing with?

Comment: @godMode: use `lstat()` first, and if that indicates it's a symbolic link, and you do want stats relevant to the linked-to file, call `stat()` as well.

Comment: @godMode: lstat() treats normal files the same way that stat() does, so you could probably just use lstat() for everything you do.

Comment: after reading the manual again i frigured i could use lstat on everything, thanks for the help everyone.